# Hide and display a picklist on onchange of lookup

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I have one field on Form of MS CRM 4, which should be hidden by default and should only be visible on selecting a specific value of lookup

I used crmForm.all.gsk_roles_c.style.display = '' on onchange event of lookup

The issue is field is hidden but values are still populating on screen without onchange event

Answer (score 0):

To hide field you should use code

```
crmForm.all.gsk_roles_c.style.display = 'none';
crmForm.all.gsk_roles_d.style.display = 'none';
```

To show field you should use code

```
crmForm.all.gsk_roles_c.style.display = '';
crmForm.all.gsk_roles_d.style.display = '';
```